# Field Filters in Salesforce Report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

My question is whether we can make field filters active dynamically only when we want the summarize the report with respect to the field used in the field filter. For E.g. if i want to summarize the report with respect to field A, then only the field filter should be applied.Is this possible?